Best approach for displaying assistive and error text together in a text field for a design system?
I’m working on different states of text fields for my design system and I’m trying to decide how to handle the combination of assistive text and error text in the error state. I’ve come up with two options but would like input on which is better, or if there’s an even more effective approach I haven’t considered.

Option 1: In the error state, display assistive text below the error text, so users can see both what the error is and the intended input format.
Option 2: In the error state, only display the error text, as showing both might clutter the field.
Which option would provide a better user experience, or is there another alternative I should consider?

It depends on the contents of the error message and the assistive text. If the error message provides basically the same information as the assistive text, showing both is redundant. Otherwise it's better to keep both. Can you provide examples of the texts? It helps eliminating the "it depends" answers.

Thank you for your input. I have another question: If I want to display both error text and assistive text, is the approach I’ve shown above the right way to go, or do you have other suggestions?

Agreed with the commenter above, some examples of the kinds of fields and messages would help with the "it depends" factor. BUT - that said, presumably the assistive text is there for remediation of the error state for that particular field. My suggestion from previous experience is to simply make it all one message below in the same treatment, done as concisely as possible.
In many cases you may not need to declare the error, the error state on the specific field gives them the context, you just indicate what they need to do to fix it.
For example, You don't need to first declare to your user that their password is non-compliant, and then give them assistive text on how to fix it; the error on the password field is enough, you just tell them how to correct the issue:

Even in less clear cases the presence of the error message on the specific field should be most of the context they need, and you can explain the error and tell them how to fix it in one shot:

(While I failed to include it in the image above, the same text might include an example of a properly formed path right in the message: "(ex: /path1/folder/filename.dbc)"
In the latter case it is possible that there will be additional issues with that DBC file itself, but those are not likely to be assessed until the submission is made; we are just trying to help them fill the form out in a way that allows them to actually submit it, and telling them how to format that entry is what they need there.
Anyway that's my $0.02 from past experience... good luck!

Thank you for your input. In a situation where the error text and assistive text are different, is the approach I've shown the right way to handle it, or is there a better alternative?

Can you give an example of a field and the two different messages?

Happy to provide what insight I can if you give me a more concrete example of the types of messages you are working with
